# R sapply is.factor

Tags: r, function, apply

I'm trying to separate a dataset into parts that have factor variables and non-factor variables.

I'm looking to do something like:

This part works:

```
factorCols <- sapply(df1, is.factor)
factorDf <- df1[,factorCols]
```

This part won't work:

```
nonFactorCols <- sapply(df1, !is.factor)
```

due to this error:

```
Error in !is.factor : invalid argument type
```

Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: [Relevant Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593934/why-cant-qnorm-in-sapply/15594648#15594648) While the questions are different enough to not be duplicates, the reasoning behind what's going on is identical

Comment: You probably don't need to split your df into factor and non-factor columns, but to do so, there is... `lapply(split(colnames(DF),factorCols),function(x) DF[,x,drop=FALSE])`  from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15118036/1191259

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Correct way:

```
nonFactorCols <- sapply(df1, function(col) !is.factor(col))
# or, more efficiently
nonFactorCols <- !sapply(df1, is.factor)
# or, even more efficiently
nonFactorCols <- !factorCols
```

Answer (score 8):

**Joshua** gave you the correct way to do it.  As for ***why***   `sapply(df1, !is.factor)` did not work:

`sapply` is expecting a function.  `!is.factor` is not a function. The bang operator returns a logical value (albeit, it cannot take `is.factor` as an argument).

Alternatively, you could use `Negate(is.factor)` which does in fact return a function.